# How to upload pdf stored in iphone to my app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a PDF or Doc file stored in iphone that i need to upload in my app .
How to upload that document.

This is what i have tried but it is showing iCloud.

```
UIDocumentMenuViewController *importMenu =
[[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:[self typeOfDocuments]
                                                     inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];

importMenu.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:importMenu animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: You can not fetch the documents resides in device memory, even due to app sandboxing you can't get the document of other Apps too

Answer (score -1):

Please see a similar question here - [iOS - How to access the device's file library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458203/ios-how-to-access-the-devices-file-library)

Long story short, it's not really possible unless you create the PDF through your app, or are passed it through a custom URL scheme.